# JS pushing value into an Object with string key and array values

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a string type key, and an array type value, the object looks like this

```
myObj = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [5. 6], c:[9] }
```

I want to add a integer inside the array of a certain key, let's say for example I want add the number 7 inside the array of key a, so the object becomes `myObj = { a: [1, 2, 3, 7], b: [5, 6], c: [9] }`

I tried doing something like `myObj["a"].push(7);`, but this completely changed the structure of `myObj`.

How should I implement this to accomplish my goal?

```js
const myObj = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [5, 6], c:[9] }
myObj["a"].push(7);
console.log(myObj)
```

Comment: you have a dot in `b` but it should work like this.

Comment: The code does exactly what you want (at least after fixing the syntax error in `5. 6`). You would have to provide a [mcve] to demonstrate what "completely changed" means.

Comment: The formatting of your objects is not a property. `{a:[1,2,3]}` and `{     a :     [1  ,       2,3] }` are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Tried These:

```
let myObj = {a: [1, 2, 3], b: [5, 6], c:[9]};
myObj.a.push(7); //Worked Correctly Will Return length of "a" Array
myObj["a"].push(7); //Worked
```

Comment: yea It worked if I do this in console, I was trying to do it in React, maybe Im having something else that is messing with the structure, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use follow as code:

```js
const myObj = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [5, 6], c:[9] }
myObj.a.push(7);
console.log(myObj)
```